# Automatically created unique id for each item in a relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I might have misunderstood how things are suppose to work but here goes.

I have a form for one item (a person), a person have several projects. Now I'd like that the generated html for the name textfield would have the name attribute to something like this: [person][0][project][name] for the first item and [person][1][project][name] for the second item and so on. And I thought that the code below would give me that, however it only produces [person][project][name] which is a problem because that entails whenever you submit this form, only one of the text fields will actually be posted.

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  ...
  <% @person.projects.each do |project| %>
    <% if project.active? %>
      <%= person_form.fields_for :projects, project do |project_fields| %>
        Name: <%= project_fields.text_field :name %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I hope following solution will help you.

```
<%= form_for @person do |person_form| %>
  i = 0
  <% @person.projects.each do |project| %>
    <% if project.active? %>
      <%= person_form.fields_for :projects, project do |project_fields| %>
        Name: <%= project_fields.text_field :name, name: "person[#{i}][project][name]" %>
      <% end %>
      <% i += 1 %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```